# Chipset Throughput

Tags: usb, chipset

My current motherboard has an Intel B150 chipset controlling the USB 3.0 connectivity and I was wondering if when the product page states a maximum of 6 USB 3.0 ports is that equivalent to the 4.8gbps transfer speed for USB 3.0 multiplied by 6 ports or 4.8gbps divided across 6 ports?

http://ark.intel.com/products/90592/Intel-B150-Chipset

Comment: It indicates that only the B150 chipset only requires a single USB 3.0 HUB, which means throughput is limited to the capacity of that single USB 3.0 HUB.  You are not going to get 6 * 4 Gbps from a single USB 3.0 HUB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Throughput of I/O subsystems in Intel architecture is defined by its "media access controller", MAC. The B150 has one xHCI USB 3.0 controller, and throughput is limited by its DMA engine parsing linked list of TRBs (Transfer Ring Buffers) from main memory. The entire pipe (PIPE3) is balanced to provide "up to 5 Gbps" (500 MBytes/s) of throughput down to USB 3.0 PHYs.

The set of downstream USB ports, however, is implemented INTERNALLY as "root hub", meaning that all physical ports share the same "PHY/MAC" bus and therefore the controller bandwidth.

Here is a block diagram for [similar chipset (Q170)](https://www.servethehome.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/Supernicro-X11SSQ-O-Block-Diagram.jpg) that shows the 5 Gbps limitation explicitly (in later diagrams this parameter was omitted, for confusion I guess). For more amusement there are [Intel publications on this topic](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/io/pci-express/phy-interface-pci-express-sata-usb31-architectures.html).